# backBarButtonItem display image incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, back-button, uinavigationitem

I'm using custom `UIBarButtonItem` with image for `backBarButtonItem`. I discovered strange behavior, because in addition to my image, the default Arrow icon is also displayed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BackButtonIcon"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }

    @IBAction private func push(_ button: UIButton) {
        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }

}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

}
```

Result is
[image]
[image: UI debugger]

Comment: So why is it *incorrect*? Is it displaying the wrong image or is it just that you have two buttons? Please edit your question to be clearer

Comment: @George_E_2 I wrote that it is incorrect because my image and the standard image are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BackButtonIcon")

navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BackButtonIcon")

navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

The navigation bar have a property for a back image as well as the backItem property which is a UINavigationItem. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar?changes=_2).

**EDIT:**

Use this code in the source view controller not the destination controller.

Comment: I know about this property but I'm wondering why I can not do, like I did above

Comment: What exactly can you not do ?

Comment: @Alexander I have edited my answer with more details to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.
Edit: this hides the native back button. You should be able to then set your own after.